# R- use of parenthesis in dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis

I was working on a dataframe with 8 rows and 5 columns. I was looking to print the last 3 rows only.

I initially wrote this:

```
last_3 <- my_df[ nrow(my_df) - 2 : nrow(my_df),]
last_3
```

This printed the first 6 rows from row number 6 to row number 1(i.e. in decreasing order)

Then I did this and it worked as expected(i.e. row numbers 6,7 and 8)

```
last_3 <- my_df[( nrow( my_df) - 2) : nrow(my_df),]
last_3
```

Can anyone explain what changes did the parenthesis bring?
And how was the output in first case generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be explained by observing that the colon `:` operator has a *higher* order of precedence than the minus `-` operator.  Here is an example which shows you what was happening, assuming that your data frame `my_df` has 4 rows:

```
my_df <- data.frame(v1=c(1,2,3,4), v2=c(1,2,3,4), v3=c(1,2,3,4))

nrow(my_df) - 2 : nrow(my_df)

4 - (2 : 4)
4 - [2, 3, 4]
[2, 1, 0]
```

In other words, you were really adding a number to the sequence `2:4`.  When you wrapped the indices with parentheses, you got the behavior you really wanted:

```
(nrow(my_df) - 2) : nrow(my_df)

(4 - 2) : 4
2 : 4
[2, 3, 4]
```